# Java: Syntax error on token "n", ++ expected after this token

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have this error in Eclipse when running this code:

```
package prova1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fattoriale {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.print("Inserisci il numero:\n");
    n = input.nextInt();
    int val = 1;

    for ( n; n>1; n-=1){
        val = val*n;

    }   

System.out.println(val);
}

}
```

I am trying to get the factorial of an n number, but I get this error and I can't figure out where the problem is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error on token "n", ++ expected after this token

at prova1.Fattoriale.main(Fattoriale.java:12)
```

I tried creating a new var i but I still get that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you cannot use `n` by itself in the first compartment of the `for` loop. However, you can leave it blank:

```
for ( ; n>1 ; n-=1) {
//   ^
// Nothing
}
```

Consider replacing `-= 1` with more conventional `--`.

If you wish to get really fancy, you could do this:

```
for ( int i = input.nextInt() ; n>1 ; n-- ) {
    // ...
}
```

**Note:** The use of `for` loop above is fine. Generally, though, one should consider using a `while` loop in place of `for` when you leave one of the three compartments blank.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved the problem!